# Google cloud storage bucket using service account in Json file from C#

Tags: c#, json, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts

I am new to c# coding world, need help to connect to Google cloud storage bucket using service account Json file from C#  need some pointers for the same.

Comment: Google should be able to give better pointers than here...

Comment: See http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/ for various samples.

Comment: I am using version  14.0.25431.01 of Visual Studio  Professional 2015, when i try to install Google Cloud tools i cant find them in Visual Studio Gallery. Is this version not supported with google cloud tools? Also when i write below code and try to run it gives error exception looks like this version is not supported hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a service account and create the JSON File.

In the GCP Console, go to the Create service account key page.

GO TO THE CREATE SERVICE ACCOUNT KEY PAGE
From the Service account drop-down list, select New service account.
In the Service account name field, enter a name .
From the Role drop-down list, select Project > Owner.
Click Create. A JSON file that contains your key downloads to your computer.

Then install the reauired plugin for your project.
If you are using Visual Studio 2017 or higher, open nuget package manager window and type the following:

```
Install-Package Google.Cloud.Storage.V1
```

If you are using .NET Core command-line interface tools to install your dependencies, run the following command:

```
dotnet add package Google.Cloud.Storage.V1
```

Then add the JSON file to your path and set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to refer to the JSON file, so that StorageClient can find it.

For the application part, here is an exemple :

```
using Google.Cloud.Storage.V1;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace GoogleCloudSamples
{
    class StorageQuickstart
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Your Google Cloud Platform project ID.
            string projectId = "YOUR-PROJECT-ID";


            // Instantiates a client.
            StorageClient storageClient = StorageClient.Create();

            // The name for the new bucket.
            string bucketName = projectId + "-test-bucket";
            try
            {
                // Creates the new bucket.
                storageClient.CreateBucket(projectId, bucketName);
                Console.WriteLine($"Bucket {bucketName} created.");
            }
            catch (Google.GoogleApiException e)
            when (e.Error.Code == 409)
            {
                // The bucket already exists.  That's fine.
                Console.WriteLine(e.Error.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One missing step here: set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to refer to the JSON file, so that `StorageClient` can find it.

Comment: True, i will add it to the answer